# std::sort and compare-function with template does not work

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, vector, std

I want to sort a vector of arbitrary types, so I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
bool compare(T a, T b) {
    return a < b;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(1);

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        cout << v.at(i) << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code is not compiling, with a error message like:

```
..\src\Test.cpp:22:34: error: no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
..\src\Test.cpp:22:34: note: candidates are:

... and more
```

When I implement the compare-function with concrete types, it works.
Can someone tell me how to do that with a template-compare-function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`compare` is not a function, it's a function template that can be used *generate* functions, such as `compare<int>` and `compare<long>`

So to pass a function to `sort` you need to name a specialization of the function template:

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare<int>);
```

Alternatively, create a function object and pass that:

```
struct Compare {
  template<typename T>
    bool operator()(T a, Tb) const { return a < b; }
};
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), Compare());
```

This function object has a member function template that can compare any types (like your `compare`) but you don't need to refer to a specific specialization when passing it to `sort`, you pass a temporary of type `Compare` and inside the `sort` algorithm the compiler will select the right specialization of the function template.

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify which specialization you want:

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare<int>);
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f595b70d0984f84)